# If a byte is 192 or any other value, is there a way to show how it is made up of its individual bit values?

Tags: c#, byte, bit

For example,

If a byte is 192, I know this will be 128 + 64 = 192

Is there a way in CSharp to list the values that make up the byte so they can be printed or used elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: "Yes, that's possible" and "What code has been tried / how is it not working?" There are plenty of questions/answers already on the topic..

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
int V = 192;
int B = 1;
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
   if (V&0x01 == 1) {
       // Use B any way you like
   }
   V/=2;
   B*=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        static string ToBinary(int input)
        {
            string[] binary = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111" };

            return string.Join("", input.ToString("x").Select(x => binary[byte.Parse(x.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)]));
        }
```

---

Or use following

```
        static string ToBinary2(int input)
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>(); ;
            while (input > 1)
            {
                results.Insert(0,(input % 2) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
                input /= 2;
            }
            return string.Join("", results) ;

        }
```